# Does there exist a natural number $N = xy$ satisfying $D(x)D(y) = 2s(x)s(y)$ with $\gcd(x,y)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

**Preamble:**  I apologize in advance if what I am asking for in this question, I could get an answer easily so myself, for example by coding a short Mathematica script.  It is just that I have not yet studied the rudiments of Mathematica (or even Python) scripting, so I am not there yet.

Let $\sigma(z)$ be the sum of the divisors of $z \in \mathbb{N}$.  Denote the deficiency of $z$ by $D(z) := 2z - \sigma(z)$ and the sum of the aliquot parts of $z$ by $s(z) := \sigma(z) - z$.

Here is my question:

> Does there exist a natural number $N = xy$ satisfying $D(x)D(y) = 2s(x)s(y)$ with $\gcd(x,y)=1$?

I would also be interested in answers to the more general question:

> Does there exist a natural number $N = xy$ satisfying $D(x)D(y) = 2s(x)s(y)$?

**MY TRY**

I note that, in general, the deficiency and sum-of-aliquot-parts functions are *not weakly multiplicative*.  That is:
$$D(xy) \neq D(x)D(y)$$
and
$$s(xy) \neq s(x)s(y)$$
when $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

In fact, I know that when $\gcd(x,y)=1$, then both the inequalities
$$D(xy) \leq D(x)D(y)$$
and
$$s(xy) < s(x)s(y)$$
hold.

Of course, $D(xy)$ and $s(xy)$ are related by the equation
$$D(xy) + s(xy) = xy.$$
We also have the equations
$$D(x) + s(x) = x$$
$$D(y) + s(y) = y.$$
Multiplying the last two equations, and equating I obtain:
$$D(x)D(y) + s(y)D(x) + s(x)D(y) + s(x)s(y) = xy = D(xy) + s(xy).$$

We are given that $D(x)D(y)=2s(x)s(y)$.  So we substitute and obtain
$$3s(x)s(y) + s(y)D(x) + s(x)D(y) = xy$$
$$3s(x)s(y) + s(y)\bigg(x - s(x)\bigg) + s(x)\bigg(y - s(y)\bigg) = xy$$
$$s(x)s(y) + xs(y) + ys(x) = xy$$
$$s(y)(s(x) + x) + s(x)(s(y) + y) = s(x)s(y)+xy.$$

It is here where I get stuck.  I feel that I am just going around in circles here.  Note that the condition
$$s(y)(s(x) + x) + s(x)(s(y) + y) = s(x)s(y)+xy$$
is derived independently of the divisibility constraint
$$\gcd(x,y)=1.$$

**POSTING WHAT FOLLOWS AS AN ANSWER TO THIS QUESTION**

> **Added April 12, 2018**
>   Now I get it!  This last condition
>   $$s(y)(s(x) + x) + s(x)(s(y) + y) = s(x)s(y)+xy$$
>   together with the divisibility constraint
>   $$\gcd(x,y)=1$$
>   simplifies to
>   $$\sigma(xy)=\sigma(x)\sigma(y)=2xy$$
>   which implies that $N = xy$ must be a [perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number).

Comment: Just to add the following code (is a line) written in Pari-GP `for (x = 1, 500,for (y = 1, 500,if((2*x-sigma(x))*(2*y-sigma(y))==2*(sigma(x)-x)*(sigma(y)-y)&&gcd(x,y)==1,print (x*y))))` Now if you need to search in internet **Sage Cell Server.** Then to run previous code,  copy&paste with the mouse, choosing *GP* as Language, and press *Evaluate.* You can find also tutorial, and reference card for Pari-GP. Also in Internet if you type, for example *euler totient, pari*, you find the code for $\varphi(n)$, or different arithmetic functions. Isn't required a response of this comment, good week.

Comment: Thanks, @user243301!  That code returns the error message
"***   syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting )-> or ',': 
  ***   ...&gcd(x,y)==1,print(x*y))))
  ***                               ^-"
when ran in **Sage Cell Server**.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks!  I was missing the initial *for* in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Added April 12, 2018**
Now I get it!  This last condition
$$s(y)(s(x) + x) + s(x)(s(y) + y) = s(x)s(y)+xy$$
together with the divisibility constraint
$$\gcd(x,y)=1$$
simplifies to
$$\sigma(xy)=\sigma(x)\sigma(y)=2xy$$
which implies that $N = xy$ must be a [perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number).