# Does there exist an odd natural number $N = xy$ satisfying $D(x)D(y) = 2s(x)s(y)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, conjectures, divisor-sum

**Preamble:**  I apologize in advance if what I am asking for in this question, I could get an answer easily so myself, for example by coding a short Mathematica script.  It is just that I have not yet studied the rudiments of Mathematica (or even Python) scripting, so I am not there yet.

This question is a follow-up to this [earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2733758).

Let $\sigma(z)$ be the sum of the divisors of $z \in \mathbb{N}$.  Denote the deficiency of $z$ by $D(z) := 2z - \sigma(z)$ and the sum of the aliquot parts of $z$ by $s(z) := \sigma(z) - z$.

Here is my question:

> Does there exist an odd natural number $N = xy$ satisfying $D(x)D(y) = 2s(x)s(y)$?

Comment: Just to add a code. Same instructions than before (my English was bad): search in Internet **Sage Cell Server**, and copy and paste with the mouse the following code (is a line) `for (x = 1, 1000,for (y = 1, 1000,if(x%2==1&&y%2==1&&(2*x-sigma(x))*(2*y-sigma(y))==2*(sigma(x)-x)*(sigma(y)-y),print (x*y))))` Secondly choose *GP* as Language and press *Evaluate*. Then when the green box of the output will black, means that the program has finished (in this example there isn't output for the range $1\leq x,y\leq 1000$, where the syntax `variable%2==1` means that the `variable` is an odd integer).

Comment: Thank you very much for this, @user243301!  This will be a big help for me when I test my number-theoretic conjectures.  ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "*YES*" for the Descartes spoof
$$\mathscr{D} = 198585576189 = {22021}\cdot{3003}^2,$$
where we set $x = 22021$ and $y = {3003}^2$.  (That is, if we *pretend* that $x = 22021$ is prime.)

We "*obtain*"
$$D(x)D(y) = 18034380 =  2s(x)s(y).$$